# Configure deployment template for application insights premium teir

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-application-insights

Here is my deployment template section for application insights. It works. But I want to deploy to a different pricing tier\quota. What is the right parameter for that?

```
 {
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
  "location": "Central US",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]": "Resource"
  },
  "properties": {
    "ApplicationId": "[parameters('siteName')]",
    "sku": "Premium"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `"sku`" parameter in your deployment template and use it as your parameter to control the pricing tier for your AI resource.

The "sku" parameter will be used by your "serverFarm" resource type to determine App Service Hosting Plan tier for your resources under the hosting plan.

```
"parameters": {
        "sku": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Free",
                "Shared",
                "Basic",
                "Standard",
                "Premium"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "Premium"
        }
}

    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "sku": {
            "name":  "P1",
            "tier": "[parameters('sku')]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('numOfWorkers')]",
            "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]"
        },
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    }

{
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
  "location": "Central US",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]"
  ],
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]": "Resource"
  },
  "properties": {
    "applicationId": "[parameters('siteName')]"
  }
```

**Update 1:**

Based on the latest ARM template schema for Microsoft Application Insight, you could not define the tier property for it.

As I have highlighted before, the tier is only defined for the "serverFarm" or better known as App Service Hosting Plan resource.

Ref: [azure-resource-manager-schemas/schemas/2014-04-01/Microsoft.Insights.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2014-04-01/Microsoft.Insights.json)

```
"components": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "Microsoft.Insights/components"
          ]
        },
        "apiVersion": {
          "enum": [
            "2014-04-01"
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "applicationId": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "description": "Microsoft.Insights/components: applicationId"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type",
        "apiVersion",
        "properties",
        "location"
      ],
      "description": "Microsoft.Insights/components"
    }
```

Comment: I tried setting the sku in my template (it's pasted in the question). It didn't work ... it was still at the free tier.

Comment: Hi @Steven, I edited my answer above as I am confused by your statement about your AI is working. The "sku" parameter should be used by your serverFarm/hostingPlan resource which determine the service tier of your App Service resources. Hope this helps.

Comment: My issue isn't with the size of my web app\service, which his what your answer now provides. (I'm already setting that one successfully) My question is about setting the quota\tier for app insights, which is independent from the hosting plan and app\service tier.

Comment: @Steven, does my updated answer address your issue or concern? If not please let me know so I can try to help

Answer (score 1):

You can now set the pricing tier and quota for app insights via an ARM template.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-powershell#create-an-azure-resource-manager-template